# Variance of rolling mean of AR(1) process

Tags: variance, autoregressive

Consider a random variable following an AR(1) model:

$$x_t = \mu+\rho x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

Assumme that $\epsilon_t$ follows $N(0,\sigma^2_\epsilon)$. The unconditional expected value of this proces is:

$$E(x_t)=\mu/(1-\rho)$$

Now take a rolling mean of $x_t$ of n periods including the current:
$$\bar{x}_t = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_{t-i}$$

Based on [Wiki: Sum of normally distributed random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511014/expected-value-of-rolling-mean-of-ar1-process/511312#511312) the expected value is still just the sum of the expected value for each  $x_t$ which is given above, hence the expected value of $\bar{x}_t$ is:

$$E(\bar{x}_t)=1/n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E(x_{t-i})=n/n  E(x_t)=E(x_t)$$

This is the result from the question here:[Expected Value of rolling mean of AR(1) process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511014/expected-value-of-rolling-mean-of-ar1-process/511312#511312)
. However, I am interested in the variance of the this rolling mean.

Here is my approach so far. First roll back the expression for $x_t$ to a common time point (the length of the rolling window):
$$x_t = \mu \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \rho^i + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \rho^i \epsilon_{t-i} + \rho^k x_{t-k}$$

Inserting this into the expression for $\bar{x}_t$ yields:
$$\bar{x}_t=1/n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\rho^{n-i}x_{t-n}+\mu\sum_{j=0}^{k-i-1}\rho^j+\sum_{j=0}^{k-i-1}\rho^{j}\epsilon_{t-i-j})$$

$$=1/n(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{t_n}\rho^{n-i}+ \mu\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^{j}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^j\epsilon_{t-i-j})$$

Taking the variance to this, I get (as the middle-part is just a constant):
$$VAR[\bar{x}_t]=VAR[\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{t-n}\rho^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^j\epsilon_{t-i-j})$$

To arrive at an expression, I have done the following:

1. Move the fraction outside VAR:
   $$=\frac{1}{n^2}VAR[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{t-n}\rho^{n-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^j\epsilon_{t-i-j}]$$
2. As there are no correlation between a previous lagged x and future error-terms, there are no correlations between the two summands (please correct me, if I am mistaken). Hence, the expression becomes:

$$=\frac{1}{n^2}VAR[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{t-n}\rho^{n-i}]+VAR[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^j\epsilon_{t-i-j}]$$

3. Find an expression for the first summand. The covariance of a variable with itself is just the variance. Hence, using the rule:
   $$VAR[\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2VAR[X_i]+\sum_{i,j=1, i <>j}^{n}a_ia_jCOV(X_i,X_j)$$
   on the first summand yields:
   $$VAR[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_{t-n}\rho^{n-i}]=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\rho^{2(n-i)}VAR[x_{t-n}] + \sum_{i,j=1, i<>j}^{n-1}\rho^{2n-i-j}VAR[x_{t-n}]$$

A simplification gives:
$$=VAR[x_{t-n}](\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\rho^{2(n-i)} + \sum_{i,j=1, i<>j}^{n-1}\rho^{2n-i-j})$$

4. Find an expression for the second summand:
   This is where I am stuck. How do I simplify this expression taking into account corelation between many of all the errors term with the same time subscript?
   $$VAR[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}\rho^j\epsilon_{t-i-j}]=?$$

Also, I am interested in the combined expression for the variance of $\bar{x}_t$.

Comment: This has popped up a few times here and there are a number of algebraically equivalent valid answers, such as this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69583/247352. If I have time later today, I will post several more links. And this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68842/247352.

Comment: And this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90082/247352.